# WebAPI SelfHost site

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

Is it possible to setup WebAPI to Self Host like Nancy.
Such that it hosts an

> /api/...

section serving up json and xml responses and hosts a

> /content/...

section serving up *.jpg and *.html and *.js

I'm trying to create a self hosting Single Page Application with WebAPI as the backend, and the only thing I have seen that comes close is Nancy.

Is this possible with WebAPI self hosting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the Katana project very interesting in your case. One of the thing it allows you to do is startup a selfhost server that can host Web API, static files, and even other frameworks like SignalR side by side.

Here's a link:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/aaf5d99f63d8#README

Filip has a blog post about getting Web API hosted on Katana:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/running-aspnet-web-api-with-owin-and-katana/

Answer (score 0):

Just blogged about that:
[Zero friction parallel self hosting of ASP.NET Web API and static files using OWIN and Katana](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2013/04/27/Zero-friction-parallel-self-hosting-of-ASPNET-Web-API-and-static-files-using-OWIN-and-Katana.aspx)